# can't authenticate user on MSAL after running ng build --prod

Tags: typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

i followed this Microsoft [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJey9KP1dZA&t=1876s) integrating MSAL in my angular app. everything works fine on the development environment but once i run ng build --prod the app doesn't authenticate users and doesn't read the auth tokens from the browser cache and i get this error
[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8ctr.png)

those are the events i'm listening to

```ts
this.broadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None)
        , takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount() && this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
          this.setAuthenticationStatus();
          this.CheckUserRole();
        }
      });


    this.broadcastService.msalSubject$
      .pipe(
        filter(
          (msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS
            || msg.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS)
      ).subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
        const payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;
        this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
        this.setAuthenticationStatus();
        this.CheckUserRole();
      });
```

Comment: `Microsoft Youtube tutorial integrating MSAL` can you please share the URL which you are following ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJey9KP1dZA&t=1876s